# Firefox add-ons: cfx run works great, cfx xpi works but the add-on does nothing

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I've been working on a Firefox extension (basically just a "content script" or "page mod", whichever term works for you) that works exactly as expected when I use "cfx run" but when I do "cfx xpi" and install it, nothing happens.  In cfx run, my content script works perfectly, with no errors from the command prompt.  If this is any help, I do see an error when I exit the test run:

```
###!!! [Child][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: (msgtype=0xAA0001,name=PTexture::Msg
___delete__) Route error: message sent to unknown actor ID
```

But this looks different from JavaScript errors (and really looks more "internal" to me, something buggy about the SDK maybe?).  Anyway, when I do cfx xpi (with or without the "--no
-strip-xpi" option) everything *seems* to work fine.  No errors from the console, the installation *seems* to work), but when I go to the page I'm writing the script for, nothing happens.  The page loads as it usually does, but the content script doesn't do anything; no changes to the page, no errors, really just no hint whatsoever of what the function is going on.

So of course I spent a bit of time on Google and also this site.  I found a couple questions that were slightly similar but either unrelated or unanswered.  Here are a few of these:
[creating xpi does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101005/creating-xpi-does-not-work) (this one was a mac vs. Windows issue)
[Create XPI package with the Add-on SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574276/create-xpi-package-with-the-add-on-sdk) (this one was kinda close but I didn't use contentScript in my main.js and did use the PageMod object like the guy suggested)
[Firefox SDK Sample Add On Exported XPI Action Button Doesn't Show Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319522/firefox-sdk-sample-add-on-exported-xpi-action-button-doesnt-show-up) (My console didn't show any errors, so this one didn't help either).

And of course, I tried all the obvious stuff (restart Firefox, reboot the computer, change the content of the scripts, etc.) and the result is still the same: fine in cfx run, compiles and installs fine but does nothing after cfx xpi.

Also, in case it would be helpful to you guys, here's my main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.somepage.com",

    // NOTE TO SELF: include all object files here.
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("Data.js"), data.url("Layout.js"), data.url("HTML.js"), data.url("Restyler.js"),     data.url("Shortcut.js"), data.url("ARIA.js"), data.url("Apricot.js")]
});
```

This follows closely with everything I've read in the documentation and tutorials, but still for whatever/no-good reason it only works in cfx run.  So unfortunately, all I can really tell you for sure is that something somewhere is somehow blocking, overriding, or otherwise preventing the XPI from doing its thing (mysterious? Sure.  Frustrating?  You have no idea...). :))))

I'm sorry I'm not sure what else to say, lol.  I know JavaScript (and a bunch of other languages) but this is my first attempt at using the SDK (which seems to be more trouble than it's worth).  Gosh I wish they would update the GreaseMonkey compiler, or at least bring back the Add-On Builder... oh crap did I say that out loud?  :)

All joking aside though, any potential solutions, workaround or other insights would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: which cfx version? which firefox version? which console did you check (there are several different  ones)? do you have e10s enabled?

Comment: Firefox 35, add-on SDK version 1.17 (including whichever version of cfx comes with that), and not sure what e10s is.  The console I was referring to is CMD (the "command prompt" (or is it "command *line*")).  One of the other consoles (the one I saw yesterday that you could bring up with Shift-Ctrl-J or whatever it was is grayed out.  And the console in the Web Developer section (Tools > Web Developer > Toggle Tools) had no errors or anything either).

Comment: the browser console greyed out? that seems odd. but you should be able to get the same (and more) debugging functionality with the [browser toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using private browsing in your Firefox setup? 
If so then you need to add

```
"permissions": {"private-browsing": true}
```

to the package.json file.

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing#Opting_into_private_browsing